# NestJS TypeORM - Entities not finished loading before services initialized

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Whenever I have a service that calls a function which needs to do some work with entities, I get errors stating that no entities of type X where found on default connection. My workarround currently is to use a setTimeout on every service constructor before calling my custom initialize methods.

Is there any other solution for this?

ServiceA

- constructor calls functionA
- functionA makes use of things like Entity.find() etc

typeorm gives error.

My workarround
ServiceA

- constructor setTimeout(cal functionA, 2seconds)
- functionA makes use of things like Entity.find() etc
- no error

Comment: do you really need to call things on constructor? instead of `setTimeout`, what if you use [`setImmediate`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#setimmediatecallback-args)?

Comment: I dont need, my workarround works but I wonder why this doesnt work right away. It looks ugly and is not very clean. 
If my service constructors need to call methods after intiantiation, they cant unless I use a timeout which is weird. There must be a way I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can try the getRepository() method of Typeform.
E.g.

await getRepository(EntityClass).count({});